# Bootstrap automatically stacking items ontop of eachother

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a bootstrap website, I have a problem. My left-handed sidebar will always stack ontop of my other items within the website.

This would be the main page. It is intended where the PTech is that it will be moved to the left-hand side of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html ng-app="employee">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/bootstrap.css">    
<title>Main Menu</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="funct">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
            <h1>Employee Database</h1>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="navbar span 3">
            <div class="navbar-inner span 3">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs span 3">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="span2">
            PTech
        </div>      
        <ng-view> </ng-view>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="footer">
        <a href="index.html">Main</a> | <a href="aboutDev.html">About               Developer</a>            
    </div>
</body>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="./JS/index.js"></script>
<script src="./JS/bootstrap.js"></script>
</html>
```

My login part that goes inside of the ng-view

```
<div class ="well" ng-model="login">
    <br />Username:
    <br/><input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="username" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username">
    <br />Password:
    <br/><input type="password" class = "span3" placeholder="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"value="Sign in" ng-click="signIn()"> {{message}}            
</div>
```

Comment: don't you need to specify `col-sm-4` class in divs?

Comment: yes that was it, always forge tsomething

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `col-sm-4` or any other column size in `child divs` of the `row` class. Documentation can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem right, but the rows don't seem to correspond with the spans.  I also noticed span 3 in your code should probably be span3

I think each row is comprised of span12.  If you want a left handed side bar, divide up the row into span3 and span9 for example, and put the left handed items in the span3 div, and the rest of the content in the span9 div